# Read image file, for compression

Tags: c++, libjpeg

So i am trying out C++, and i will start with something, and i guess, simply compressing an images should be fairly simple.

And my code is:

```
void main(){
    struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
    jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);
    FILE* outfile = fopen("/tmp/test.jpeg", "wb");
    jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, outfile);

    //cinfo.image_width      = xinfo.width;
    //cinfo.image_height     = xinfo.height;
    //cinfo.input_components = 3;
    //cinfo.in_color_space   = JCS_RGB;

    jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
    /*set the quality [0..100]  */
    jpeg_set_quality (&cinfo, 75, true);
    jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, true);
    jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);
}
```

Which i took and changed a bit form another site.

Though as you can see, Xinfo doesn´t exist, and in that example i found, it was a screenshot library or something.

So i simply want to feed it an image i got on my harddrive and compress it. Don´t want to make it harder than necessary.

http://www.andrewewhite.net/wordpress/2008/09/02/very-simple-jpeg-writer-in-c-c/

Comment: Actually I think that image compression is a quite complex starting point into C++; and the code you found is C

Comment: Small point but I can't see any C++ in your code....

Comment: Well better than nothing.

And about C++, new to this, so maybe this is just C or something?

Comment: Any chance you could post the link to the "other site" - maybe it does some explanation for example what it is for. There also seems to be a bit of repetition in your code...

Comment: Added it. And yeah noticed that i failed a bit there, will fix that.

Comment: The *very* first line of code at the website is `#include <jpeglib.h>`, and that's not in your sample. But the cause of your error is because you didn't follow instructions: "..take a screen shot using Xlib. Note that Xlib this has next to nothing to do with the JPEG code and is only included to create a context." That 'context' creates the actual *image* you are going to compress.

Comment: I have added jpeglib, didn´t show that, sorry. And well, i don´t want to take a screnshot and compress, i just want to give it a picture on my PC, so i can understand how it works. Just take the image compress save. Not something flashy as taking a printscreen, that will be step 2:)

Comment: @user2587718: the xlib and 'context' stuff is to load some -- *any* -- image into memory, so the jpeg library has something to compress. You are overlooking the fact that to compress an image, the very first thing is to load an image file into memory. It's not rocket science (compared to JPEG compression), but nevertheless you should start with that. Try opening any image file and displaying it on screen *without using any library or specifically designed system call*. Suitable file formats to play with are TGA (deceptively easy) and BMP (lots of nice little pitfalls). Then look in to saving.